# Difference of using association name or column name in Active Query find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 4.0, is there a performance difference / recommended practice between the following two ways?

```
Post.find_by user: user
```

vs.

```
Post.find_by user_id: user.id
```

Comment: Don't think any of them would work. You need to try (Post.find_by_id user.id)

Comment: @ashwinkumar actually, both of them work in Rails 4.

Comment: @ashwinkumar find_by_... family is deprecated in Rails 4 (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)

Comment: Its my bad. I should have looked properly.

Comment: There's no difference in performance. The first notation seems a little bit more idiomatic.